# How to implement an admin template with react js?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, admin, react-admin

I am building an online course platform using reactjs. I am using firebase as storage, database, authentication and hosting. I want to create an admin page using react-admin-firebase. 
My question is should I create a separate app for the admin panel and where should I host it or should I include it in the folder structure of the original app, if so how should I organise the folder structure of my original app. It is my first website so any info about this would be very appreciated!

Thank you

Comment: You should add your research in the form of code you've written

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to make the answer clearer...

You could have subfolders to hold all admin related pages and components:

```
├── components
    ├── global
    │   └── Navbar.tsx
    │   └── Footer.tsx
    ├── main
    │    ...
    │   └── Home.tsx
    │   └── About.tsx
    │   └── Login.tsx
    │   └── Register.tsx
    │    ...
    ├── admin
    │   └── Dashboard.tsx
    │   └── Manage.tsx
    │    ...
    │   └── Settings.tsx
```

And in your components, you define the ProtectedRoute component

```
...
export default const ProtectedRoute = ({ path: Path, component: Component, ...rest }) => (
  <Route
    path={Path}
    render={props =>
    //Custom login check to be implemented by you
      logggedIn ? (
        <Component {...props} />
      ) : (
        <Redirect to="/login" />
      )
    }
  />
);
```

Then wherever you define your routes, I assume `App.tsx`

```
<Route exact path="/" render={props => <Main {...props} />} />
<ProtectedRoute path="/admin" component={admin} />
```

Comment: Since I am using firebase authentication do I need a protected route for the admin or can I use firebaseauth in the admin component to check if the user that is signed in is an admin and if not to redirect them back to homepage?

Comment: Reactjs uses its own route, it is good to write your login verification logic in one component, as suggested to you, in protected route; otherwise, you have to write login verification logic in each admin component(or page). You can implement firebase authentication or any other api authentication method of your choice.

Answer (score 1):

In Reactjs you create reusable UI components. Keep your related components in their directory, just a suggestion, you can arrange the way you want. Anywhere in your project, you import components using an import statement and use those components. **For ADMIN panel just specify a PROTECTED route, after authentication and authorization the admin user can access admin related pages**.